# Timestamp in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, timestamp

I am trying to decode the timestamp updated in elasticsearch, I am using the filebeats to update the data into the elasticsearch and I get the default timestamp format in the **{index}/_mapping** like below,

```
"@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
```

**Example** :

```
2020-10-12T15:49:00.976Z
```

Year : 2020
Month : 10
Date : 12
Hour : 15
Minutes : 49
Seconds : 00

**What is the 976, Is it the millisecond?**

Comment: Harry - Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 976 is the milliseconds. More info at [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Generally speaking, this timestamp adheres to the form `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` which is, among other things,  a [built-in ElasticSearch date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) also called `date_optional_time` or `strict_date_optional_time`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the 976, Is it the millisecond?

Yes, it is the `millisecond` within the second.

### Proof:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-10-12T15:49:00.976Z");
        System.out.println(instant.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
976
```